# Dynamic route not working on page refresh with Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

I'm used Next.js but i have an error with dynamic route.

In my application I use `getStaticPaths`, `getStaticProps` and this:

```js
<Link
    href={`/offers/[id]?id=${offer.id}`}
    as={`/offers/${offer.id}`}
>
    <a>{offer.title}</a>
</Link>
```

When I click on this link, I have no problem with the dynamic route to display my page.

But when I refresh the same page, I get this message:

[image]

When I looked for a solution the answer was that my `Link` did not have the right setting when clicked on.

But now I don't click on the link, I just refresh my page.

I use **Next.js 10.0.7**

Answer (score 4):

Since Next.js `9.5.3` there's no longer the need to use `as` for dynamic routes. Instead you can directly use the value to interpolate in `href`.

```js
<Link href={`/offers/${offer.id}`}>
    <a>{offer.title}</a>
</Link>
```

Alternatively, you can also use a different `Link` syntax by passing a URL object to it.

```js
<Link
    href={{
        pathname: '/offers/[id]',
        query: { id: offer.id }
    }}
>
    <a>{offer.title}</a>
</Link>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer but I still have the same problem. My link works fine, the problem comes from the reloading of the page every time I refresh it gives me this error.

Comment: And you still get the same error even with the change I suggested?

Comment: hello yes but I try several changes to see if it comes from my code if i find a solution or an answer of my problem i can post it.

Comment: @jeanA Does your link still work? Neither of mine, link or page refresh, works. The same error is thrown. Have any idea?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. But I've been working with translations on the website.

So when I change selected language on any page it works fine, but as soon as I change language on any of the [id] page (item, article, etc.) I got the same error as you have.

In my case the problem was inside `router.push()` method I've used.
So when I pass `router.pathname` it returns `/articles/[id]` literally.

But actually I needed to use `router.asPath` which returns the correct URL path, such as `/articles/abc123-456zczxc-7890-blablabla`.

Here is an example from NextJS docs:

`pathname`: `String` - Current route. That is the path of the page in /pages, the configured basePath or locale is not included.

`asPath`: `String` - The path (including the query) shown in the browser without the configured basePath or locale.

[NextJS API Reference Link](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've been struggling with this for last 2 days. :)